# Regex french phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, phone-number

I have an input I want to limit some phone number format like

> 0612352512 *or* 0125357878

but not

> 0025577787 *or* +3327487877 *or* nothing else.

My regex work for some caracter, but **0000000000** or **5555555555** is always accept...

```js
$("#tel").focusout(function(){
  var numTel = $(this).val();
  // var rgxPhone = /(([0-9]{2})[-. ]?){5}/
  var rgxPhone = /(([0-9]{2})){5}/
  if ( !numTel.match(rgxPhone)){
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("error");
    $(".nope").css({
      color:'#F70421',
      "font-weight":"bold",
      display: 'block'
    });
    $(".oke").css({display: 'none'});
  }else{
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("ok");
    $(".oke").css({
      color:'#84BD00',
      "font-weight":"bold",
      display: 'block'
    });
    $(".nope").css({display: 'none'});
  }
});
```

```css
input.defaut{
  border: #9B9697 1px solid;
}

input.error{
  border: #F70421 1px solid;
}

input.ok{
  border: #84BD00 1px solid;
}

.nope, .oke{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for"tel">Numéro de téléphone</label>
<input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" size="11" maxlength="10" class="defaut check">
  <p class="nope">Nope !</p>
  <p class="oke">Ok !</p>
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: The `/(([0-9]{2})){5}/` matches 5 occurrences of any 2 digits anywhere inside the string. What are your rules?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah that is an odd pattern. Essentially "even number of digits, up to ten".

Comment: And do you have any solution :/ ?
My rules ares
Start by 0
Next is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9
And the next is 8 digit suit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My rules ares Start by 0 Next is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9 And the next
>   is 8 digit suit

Use:

```
/0[1-9]\d{8}/
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/lQ1tU8/1)

Comment: Well, i didn't noticed the 8 was missing, but u got the idea ;-)